# List all the tags from a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, tags

I'm looking for solution that will display all the tags that are used on a custom post type. I just want to list them all because I'm going to add jQuery code on each tag. :)

Comment: Please avoid words like `coz`. There are tons of non native english speakers here and probably some will not understand what you wrote later on. At least it's no chat here. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[wp_get_object_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms) will have your answer.

`wp_get_object_terms( $post_ids, 'post_tag', $optional_args );`

There is also [get_the_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) which is simpler but also gets the job done.

`get_the_terms( $id, 'post_tag');`

Comment: Thanks, it takes time for me to accomplish and now i'm done.. Thanks @sneek.. you are awesome..

Answer (score 4):

[`the_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_terms)

Both `the_tags()` and `the_terms()` uses `get_the_term_list()`, the different is that `the_tags()` has the default put in for `post_tag`.

Watch them in `wp-includes/category-template.php`